# Valac won't let me "install_style_property" from a static method

Tags: gtk, vala

I would like to use Gtk.Widget's `ìnstall_style_property ()` on a widget I'm writing. In the docs, this method is declared as `static`, so I am wondering why valac still complains that I am calling it from a static method:

```
public class MyClass : Gtk.Widget {

    public static void init () {
        ParamSpecDouble _the_property = new ParamSpecDouble
        (
            "dummy", "dummy", "dummy,
            0, double.MAX, 0,
            ParamFlags.READWRITE | ParamFlags.STATIC_STRINGS
        );
        install_style_property (_the_property);
    }
}

void main (string? argv) {
    Gtk.init (ref argv);
    MyClass.init ();
}
```

The error message:

> test.vala:11.9-11.46: error: Access to instance member `Gtk.Widget.install_style_property' denied

If this does not work, what is the preferred pattern to install custom style properties to a custom widget in Gtk? Personally, I would prefer not to have to call an `init ()` before using my widget, but as adding style properties is done per-class instead of per-instance, putting it into the constructor does not seem right, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`install_style_property()` is not `static`; it's actually a `class` method. valadoc.org is showing `static` for some reason; you'll probably have to report that as a bug (if it hasn't already).

`class` methods operate *on a class itself*. GObject classes have shared metadata, and these methods modify that metadata. Such metadata should only be modified when the class is first initialized; therefore, the methods should only be called within that class's `GObjectClass.class_init()` method. In Vala, this is the `static construct` method:

```
public class MyClass : Gtk.Widget {

    static construct {
        ParamSpecDouble _the_property = new ParamSpecDouble
        (
            "dummy", "dummy", "dummy,
            0, double.MAX, 0,
            ParamFlags.READWRITE | ParamFlags.STATIC_STRINGS
        );
        install_style_property (_the_property);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not marked as static, it's marked as class.  See https://git.gnome.org/browse/vala/tree/vapi/gtk+-3.0.vapi?id=48ca4e0fc480c3610e3a115376b86a1cee6c68f2#n6782

Comment: @nemequ then it's a valadoc.org issue (valadoc.org has lots of issues lately, it seems...)

Comment: Ah, I didn't even think to look at valadoc (I usually just use vapis and c docs).  That's probably not a new issue; class methods are quite rare, so there is probably some faulty logic where it assumes that !instance == static.